# Is there any solution for sending the result of a counter to a list in pyhton?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I wrote a code for a counter in python, but I did not my appropriate result.
I made a list by input numbers,then **wanted to make a counter and send the result of the counter in a new list and print it:**
How can I do that?

```
`>>>num1=int(input("plz enter a number: "))
 >>>num2=int(input("plz enter a number: "))
 >>>num3=int(input("plz enter a number: ")) 
 >>>list1= [num1,num2,num3] 
 >>>for n in list1:
 >>>   n=n+1
 >>>   print(n)`
```

the result after input numbers would be:

```
plz enter a number: 32
plz enter a number: 15
plz enter a number: 18
33
16
19
```

but I want to see 33,16,19 in a list. like:

```
[33,16,19]
```

Comment: Can you add an example on how your output should look like?

Comment: Do you want the new list to be `[num1+1, num2+1, num3+1]`?

Comment: @SergeBallesta yes I want to see the result like ```[num1+1, num2+1, num3+1]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic way to create a now list in Python is called a *comprehension*:

```
list2 = [i+1 for i in list1]
```

It is almost equivalent but shorter and more efficient (we say more *pythonic*) than:

```
list2 = []
for i in list1:
    list2.append(i+1)
```